# How to pass correct html select value to $_POST php

Tags: php, html, select, post

I have tried html like this:

```
<form method="post">
   <select id="select" size="2 ">
        <option value="3">test</option>
        <option value="4">test2</option>                     
   </select>
   <button type="submit" value="execute">
</form>
```

How do I get a 3 or 4 value in the post array

```
$_POST['select']
```

?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add the name tag...

```
<select id="select" name="select" size="2 ">
```