# Is it possible to $_POST the value of Option on a Drop Down Menu?

Tags: php

For example

```
<select>
<?php

$option1 = $row['first']
$option2 = $row['last']
$thisval = $row['id']


echo "
     <option value='$thisval'>$option1 $option2</option> ";

?>
</select>
```

I am trying to $_POST['option']['value']?? and $_GET['option'] for my query in my post page. I believe my syntax is incorrect.

How do you find the value of Option in $_GET?

Comment: Typically the value is posted as a value of the name of the select tag.`$_POST["select_name"]` or similar with GET. Whether it be POST or GET depends on the method you use to submit it to the server.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425210/how-to-pass-correct-html-select-value-to-post-php

Comment: your code and your question have many wrong parts first of all you should distinct php from html you can not use php variables in the middle of the html unless you use php tags(<?php ?>) inside the html and echo the variables also $_GET is a global variable if you assign value to $_GET you can use its content moreover for $_POST Daniel is right.

Comment: Nick, i just updated my post a little with the other tags. I realized after reading another post my select was missing a name. My issue now is, is should my value instead be the id? If this is the case, how would I $_GET the option id then? in the end i need to get $_GET['$thisval']" is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `select` has a name.

```
<select name="foo">
    <option value="bar">bar</option>
</option>
```

Then in `$_GET` (or `$_POST`) you will have `$_GET["foo"]` with value `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

so you want to display POST data in a dropdown field? Try this.

```
<select>
<?php foreach($_POST as $option => $value){ ?>
  <option value='$value'>$option</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select element needs a name.

```
<select name="myOptions">
    <option value='$thisval'><?php echo "$option1 $option2" ; ?></option>
</select>
```

In your post, you'd do `$_POST['myOptions']`.