# How should I label a select drop down list so the choice is passed to my php script?

Tags: php, html

I have kind of mastered input boxes. I put them as gaps in a text in a form, the student fills in the gaps and sends the form, which calls the php.

```
<form action="php/thankyou18BEsW1.php" method="POST" name="myForm" onsubmit="return checkForExpiration();" >
```

> `Some text<INPUT TYPE="Text" NAME="G1" size="15"> some more text.`

My php script has at the top:

```
  //should mail the contact form
<?php
$studentnr = $_POST['sn'];
$q1 = $_POST['G1'];
```

and sure enough, the value in the textbox G1, and all the others, get sent to me OK.

Soemtimes, I would like to use a drop-down box. The students should choose a word. Here on stackoverflow I found the following. I hope that is the right way to do this!

```
<select >
<option value="" disabled selected>Please select a word...</option> 
<option>this</option>
<option>that</option>
</select>
```

I'm not quite sure where to put NAME="G1". In  `<select>` or in `<option>` ???

When I do this with radio buttons I have banks of radio buttons like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="G30" value="A">A
<input type="radio" name="G30" value="B">B
<input type="radio" name="G30" value="C">C
<input type="radio" name="G30" value="D">D
```

and that works. So I'm thinking I should put name="G1" in

```
<option name="G1">this</option>
<option name="G1">that</option>
<option name="G1">whatever</option>
```

Will that work like that? Is there some other, better way?

Comment: `<select name='g1'>`

Comment: Give it a `name` attribute and don't disable it.

Comment: with the select tag you define the name of the field. with the option tags, you define the values of the field.

Comment: Disabled, only means that the visitor can't change the value with keyboard/mouse. But the value is stil passed in the request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass correct html select value to $\_POST php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425210/how-to-pass-correct-html-select-value-to-post-php)

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="country_code">
    <option value="us">United States</option>
    <option value="fr">France</option>
</select>
```

and then in PHP:

```
$countryCode = $_POST['country_code'];
if ($countryCode === 'fr') { /*...*/ }
```